# how to get last 24 hours records from mysql DB divided by 60 minutes interval

Tags: mysql

I want to get last 24 hours data from Mysql Database.
With the condition(WHERE columnname> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 24 HOUR), We can get last 24 hours data.

My requirement is for example now the time is '25-05-2015 19:20', I need to group the 24 hours records in the below intervals as

```
1 . '25-05-2015 19:20' to '25-05-2015 18:20'
2 . '25-05-2015 18:20' to '25-05-2015 17:20'
--------------------------
24 . '24-05-2015 19:20' to '24-05-2015 18:20'
```

How can I group the 24 hours data to get the above interval result, Please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, sorry

```
SELECT COUNT(*), TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, your_date, NOW()) AS hours 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY hours
HAVING hours <= 24;
```

Hope can help you!

Comment: Hi Munoz, thanks you, by modifying the above query slightly I got the result, I have another doubt, I'm using "group by"clause on visit tableas group by visitedDateTime, Each visited user has associated with a visitor_session_id, If the user visits each page on my website It inserts records in visit Table, In visit table multiple records are there per single visitor, and all these records contains unique Visitor_session_id, Suppose If I use VisitedDateTime in Group By and distinct(Visitor_session_id) in select clause, the resultant records contains duplicate visitor_session id's in diff.times

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand, what do you need exactly?

Comment: Hi Munoz, In visit table for each visitor there are multiple records, I should get only the recent visit record based on the unique VisitorsessoinID, this visitorsessionID field is available in all visit records of the visitor. I want to get unique record for each visitor based on the visitorsessionid, for this I'm using group by visitorsessionid, upto this no problem, I need to group by based on visitedtime also, when I use group by visitorsessionid,visitedtime, I got multiple visited records for same customer in two different time intervals, this is due to visiteddatetime field in groupby.

Comment: My requirement is how can I get unique visitor record from visit table even the visitor has multiple records, How can we avoid duplicate session id in groupby visiteddatetime condition

Comment: Hi Munoz, I want to add the two values in group by result. Query : select count(visited_page),visited_page as count from visit group by visited_page  Result : (3,cart), (8,checkout), (2,login), Is there any way to perform division like 8(checkoutcount)/3(cartcount), please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATEDIFF(NOW(), your_date) AS days 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY days 
HAVING days <= 24;
```

:)

Comment: That's the way I pretend to help you, after this you can build the query on your way (for example using days+1 or days <24 or using other thing instead count(*))

Comment: The above returns count group by DAY, I want last 24 hours data group by 60 minutes interval